# Adb shell command equivalent to swiping an app from the recent tasks

Tags: android, task, adb

As the question says I'm looking for an adb shell command that is equivalent to swiping an app off the recent tasks list.

I've found one possible command `adb shell am force-stop <app>` but I'm not sure if force stop is the same as swiping it off the task list.

Are there any such commands ? Thanks.